# how to remove all website addresses in bulk using regex

Tags: regex

I have a lot of sites and I want to delete all of the web site address.

example:

```
http://www.website1.com/product.php?id=
http://www.website2.net/list.php?cid=
http://www.website3.org/view.php?page=
```

once removed:

```
product.php? id =
list.php? cid =
view.php? page =
```

I want to remove them in bulk using regex101 or regex on notepad ++

I want to ask what the code regullar expression to remove all of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find PHP Live Regex easier to use for that purpose since you see the replace results directly (choose `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`):

You can use this regex and choose replace and only keep the first capturing group `$1`:

```
(?:[a-z]{4,5}://[a-z.0-9]*\/)?([a-z.\?_=]*)([0-9]*)
```

Result:

```
product.php?id=
list.php?cid=
view.php?page=
```

See: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/g5q

Comment: i want to ask again, how to remove the number ? http://prntscr.com/bhfce6

Comment: You're welcome! I've edited againg to match both `http://example.com?test=123` and `example.com?test=123`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `regex` to search in Notepad++:

`.*\/` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC5tB4/2)

Then use a space to replace.

Basically we are searching for the last `/` and removing everything from beginning to that position.